# Ubuntu and Mint slow on host, fast on VM

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, boot

*A little background:*

I use Ubuntu as a VM with 512MB RAM and a 1 core processor. It runs good and needs about 30 seconds to start. 
Then I used a live cd to try it on a Host with 4GB RAM and quad-core. Still ran ok. Then I installed it. Booting time went up to about 2.5 minutes. (including load of Unity after password input).
I thought this was host related. 
Now I have the exact same behaviour with Mint: 3+ minutes to start. Especially the black screen after password entering takes forever. Also the usage itself is slow. This is a 2GB RAM i5, but I need about 10 seconds to open a file explorer. And about 5 to 7 seconds to open some system settings window. (this is a newly installed system btw)

**Does anyone has any clue, why it is so low?** (Am I the only who experiences such a lack of speed?)

I tried setting swappiness to 10. Shutting down nbt, bluetooth, print server. Nothing helps

Comment: Most likely the virtual disk that the VM reads from is cached in-memory (or at least parts of it) on the host.  The VM then boots reading from memory believing it is reading from disk (pretty fast).  During a real boot you do need to actually read from disk (normally rather slow).  Your disk may also be particularly slow.

Comment: See the output of `dmesg`. You may have a problem with interrupts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
I used *e4rat* to 'defragment'(?) the applications. I made rough measures of 6minutes for boot before and about 30secounds afterwards.